# Why does DHCP Server prefer unicasting over broadcasting and at what cost?

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

According to [this book](https://isbndb.com/book/9780133594140) the DHCP Offer *must* be broadcast, yet sniffing DHCP packets: it looks like neither OFFER nor ACK is broadcast (or am I mistaken here?). The screenshot was taken during:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

[image: dhcp packets]

I'd assume broadcasting would help with multiple DHCP servers for them to determine whether their offer was accepted or not; but then again REQUEST part is already broadcast and it has decisive information as to determine which offer the client wants to accept. In other words, the other DHCP Servers' offers are therefore implicitly declined.

I've reviewed the questions [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/29168/42595), [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/42832/42595) and [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/11120/42595). But I believe those questions & answers focus on *how* whereas I want to focus on the reasoning. I am curious as to why the OFFER claimed to must have been broadcast, and then again why it prefers *not* to be? How come the DHCP Server assumes that the discovering host has that certain IP address?(I believe that because frame: 179 does seem to have an ipv4 destination of a certain IP address which coincides with that of what the DHCP server offers). What might be the concern of the book to claim that it must be broadcast where indeed it *can* be not?

Comment: [this seems a nice explanation and also mentions DHCP relay](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dhcp-relay-agent-in-computer-network/#:~:text=In%20DORA%20process%2C%20the%20discover,0%2Cthe%20messages%20are%20unicast.)

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757849/7032856) is a good explanation.

Comment: May I know how did you captured this wirshark package (by running which command)? Actually, I collected a capture from my side and found that DHCP Offer and Ack packages were sending from DHCP server or router and the destination was also 255.255.255.255.

Comment: @Sunny I've added that information to the question.

Answer (score 5):

#### According to this book the DHCP Offer must be broadcast

It depends on whether the DNS Server is on the same network as the Client.

The book is slightly misleading as in book the example shows a DNS Relay Request (when the server is present on a different network).

**DNS server is on the same network as the client**

In your example the DNS server is on the same network as the client and we can go to the appropriate [RFC 2131 - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131#page-13) to see what it specifies:

> **3. The Client-Server Protocol**

...

> 1. The client broadcasts a DHCPDISCOVER message on its local physical
>    subnet.  The DHCPDISCOVER message MAY include options that suggest
>    values for the network address and lease duration.  BOOTP relay
>    agents may pass the message on to DHCP servers not on the same
>    physical subnet.
> 2. Each server may respond with a DHCPOFFER message that includes an
>    available network address in the 'yiaddr' field (and other
>    configuration parameters in DHCP options).  Servers need not
>    reserve the offered network address, although the protocol will
>    work more efficiently if the server avoids allocating the offered
>    network address to another client.  When allocating a new address,
>    servers SHOULD check that the offered network address is not already in use; e.g., the server may probe the offered address
>    with an ICMP Echo Request.  Servers SHOULD be implemented so that
>    network administrators MAY choose to disable probes of newly
>    allocated addresses.  **The server transmits the DHCPOFFER message
>    to the client**, using the BOOTP relay agent if necessary.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the `DHCPOFFER` is **not** broadcast - it is sent directly to the client.

> 5. **The client receives the DHCPACK message with configuration
>    parameters**.  The client SHOULD perform a final check on the
>    parameters (e.g., ARP for allocated network address), and notes the
>    duration of the lease specified in the DHCPACK message.  At this point, the client is configured.  If the client detects that the
>    address is already in use (e.g., through the use of ARP), the
>    client MUST send a DHCPDECLINE message to the server and restarts
>    the configuration process.  The client SHOULD wait a minimum of ten
>    seconds before restarting the configuration process to avoid
>    excessive network traffic in case of looping.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the `DHCPACK` is **not** broadcast - it is sent directly to the client.

**DNS server is on a different network to the client**

As mentioned in the link [DHCP Relay Agent in Computer Network - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dhcp-relay-agent-in-computer-network/#:%7E:text=In%20DORA%20process%2C%20the%20discover,0%2Cthe%20messages%20are%20unicast.) posted by [Zina](https://superuser.com/users/539111/zina) in a comment the process is different when DNS Relay (when the server is present on a different network) is involved:

> In DORA process, the discover and request message is broadcast, the offer and the acknowledgement message is broadcast or unicast depending upon the value of broadcast flag i.e. **If the value of broadcast flag is 1,then the offer and acknowledgement message is broadcast and if 0,the messages are unicast**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

> DHCP relay agent is any TCP/IP host which is used to forward requests and replies between DHCP server and client when the server is present on a different network. Relay agents receive DHCP messages and then generate a new DHCP message to send out on another INTERFACE.

**DORA**

- (**D**)iscovery: The client sends a broadcast to the network to find a DHCP server.
- (**O**)ffer: The DHCP server sends a unicast “offering” of an IP address to the client.
- (**R**)equest: The client broadcasts to all servers that it has accepted the offer.
- (**A**)cknowledge: The DHCP server sends a final unicast to the client that includes the IP information the client will use.

This if the client and server are in same network. The clients broadcast of the request will ensure that all other DHCP servers except the one which offer was accepted will stop reserving the IP for the offer sent out.

Comment: To add:I always remember the DORA abbrev - (D)iscovery: The client sends a broadcast to the network to find a DHCP server. (O)ffer: The DHCP server sends a unicast “offering” of an IP address to the client. (R)equest: The client broadcasts to all servers that it has accepted the offer. (A)cknowledge: The DHCP server sends a final unicast to the client that includes the IP information the client will use. This if in same network. The clients broadcast of the request will ensure that all other DHCP servers except the one which offer was accepted will stop reserving the IP for the offer sent out.

Comment: Nice. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: well, my MCSA 2003 training in 2005 finally paid out :) - had great teachers and the course was my entrance into the World of Servers. Me and DORA go far back.... And many forget that you could have multiple DHCP servers, so definitely something to remember and the reason why the client broadcasts the request. And just noticed we missed the following: if the client does not get an ACK - it will restart the process...

Comment: Another piece of info is the renewal of the IP, the windows client will ask the same DHCP server after 50% of the lease time to renew the IP, this is unicast. And if I remember correctly, if no answer it will try again after 80% and then 90% after which it will start the "I need an IP" request with broadcast from scratch...